# How to do a while loop when using a greater than or less than

Tags: python, while-loop, python-3.7

I don't understand why my while loop is continuous, how do I make it stop?

I have tried to create a while loop based on the greater than and less than figures and it has worked but my output is continuous and will not stop.

```
lineno=int(input("how many lines do you want of RLA code?"))

target= 3

while lineno >= target:
    print("Proceed")

while lineno< target: 
    print ("try again")
```

I want the output to keep asking until they get a user input of equal to or bigger than 3, and when they get a number bigger than 3 or equal to 3, I want them to proceed to ask them a different question using user input rather than continuously print "proceed" or "true".

Comment: Either `lineno` or `target` needs to be updated inside loop. Do you mean to use `if`?

Comment: This is expected because your condition lineno is 3 which is equal to target and hence it prints proceed

Answer (score 2):

You should keep on asking how many lines user need in a loop rather than printing Proceed in a loop like below:

```
while lineno < target:
    lineno=int(input("how many lines do you want of RLA code?"))
print("Proceed")
```

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand why my while loop is continuous, how do I make it stop?

Because you aren't updating the variable `lineno` in your while loop. You could try to move the input statement under the while loop.

> I want the output to keep asking until they get a user input of equal to or bigger than 3

You have answered your own question. If you want to ask the user or repeat a particular code particular number of times, you should consider moving it under `while` statement or `for` statement in `python`.

> I want them to proceed to ask them a different question using user input rather than continuously print "proceed" or "true".

You can add the new question after the `while 1:` (see my comment).

Find an example code below. It should work as you want it to be but I would suggest give it try again and try to implement the solution in your own way.

```
def askUser():
    while 1:
        lineno = int(input("how many lines do you want of RLA code?"))
        target = 3

        if lineno >= target:
            print("Proceed")
            break

        if lineno < target: 
            print ("try again")

    # Ask a different question


askUser()
```